# A browser cannot find a file on localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, php, localhost

OS Linux Mint onto VirtualBox

I've installed PHP like in this manual, 
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486

When I am trying to test PHP and go to http://localhost/testphp.php
it gives me this, "The requested URL /testphp.php was not found on this server." 
But I have it,

```
danko-VirtualBox www # pwd
/var/www
danko-VirtualBox www # ls
html  testphp.php
danko-VirtualBox www # cat < testphp.php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and apache is working.

Some previous steps

```
danko-VirtualBox danko # killall nginx
danko-VirtualBox danko # netstat -punta | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      597/smbd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1246/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1835/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      597/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      597/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1835/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      597/smbd     


 danko-VirtualBox danko # sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
php5 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdegames-card-data
  kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools
  language-selector-common libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libgcrypt20
  libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdegames6abi1 libkdesu5 libkdeui5
  libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5
  libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4
  libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkubuntu0
  libkxmlrpcclient4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3
  libpolkit-qt-1-1 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqt4-qt3support
  libqtmultimediakit1 libsolid4 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0
  libthreadweaver4 libutempter0 ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 plasma-scriptengine-javascript
  qtdeclarative4-kqtquickcharts-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 315 not upgraded.

 danko-VirtualBox danko # sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
                                                                         [ OK ]
```

Comment: what happens when you put "testphp.php" in "/var/www/html/"

Answer (score -1):

It started to work after I reinstalled PHP with command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```